# How to generate WSDL 2.0 with JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, w3c

This questions may be silly but I haven't found a way to get a WSDL 2.0 generated by a JAX-WS RI Web service.

I've been using the latest jax-ws version and if I create a very simple WS (such as the example below), the generated WSDL will be version 1.1.

```
    @WebService
    public interface RandomNumberGenerator {

        Integer getRandomNumber();

    }

    @WebService(endpointInterface="RandomNumberGenerator")
    public class RandomNumberGeneratorImpl {

       public Integer getRandomNumber() {
            return (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
       }    
    }
```

Does anyone know how I explicitly tell JAX-WS to generate a WSDL 2.0? Considering 2.0 is the W3C recommendation since 2007, I'm pretty confident JAX-WS does offer a way to generate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm pretty confident JAX-WS does offer a way to generate it.

I'm afraid, it does not. To quote from [the JAX-WS 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxws-2_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), page 2, section Goals:

> WSDL 2.0: The W3C is expected to progress WSDL 2.0[11] to Recommendation
>   during the lifetime of this JSR. JAX-WS 2.0 will add support for WSDL
>   2.0 whilst requiring continued support for WSDL 1.1. Note: The expert group for the JSR decided against this goal for this release . We will
>   look at adding support in a future revision of the JAX-WS
>   specification.

This means that there will be no WSDL 2.0 support in JAX-WS 2.0 which is why the reference implementation does not provide it. Afaik, there is not much advance in this area at the moment.

If you want WSDL 2.0 along JAX-WS, you will have to use another stack, such as [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/).

Comment: Has this changed by now ? Is it now possible ? How is it in case of glassfish 4?

Comment: There has been no update to JAX-WS (nor is one planned for Java 9, afaik), so this has not changed. I am also not aware of WSDL-related updates in glassfish 4. To be honest, I would be very surprised if WSDL 2.0 would ever be supported.